# Is there a way to make PyUnit stay showing when done in PyDev?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

When I run PyUnit from PyDev, some of my stubbed out methods print messages and cause Eclipse to switch to the console tab. Is there a way to prevent that so that PyUnit is left showing after all tests run?

Comment: You found a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are saying that your PyUnit output switches to the output tab then I am assuming that you have output on the PyUnit window as well as the Console. In order to make sure that the PyUnit window stays showing you need to go to the **Console** window in eclipse and uncheck the icons for "Show Console When Standard Out Changes" and "Show Console When Standard Error Changes". This worked for me using Eclipse 4.2.2. I suspect it will work in earlier versions too.

[image: Console window icons]

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. It looks promising!